# es6 spread operator - mongoose result copy

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I'm developping an express js API with mongo DB and mongoose.

I would like to create an object in Javascript es6 composed of few variables and the result of a mongoose request and want to do so with es6 spread operator :

```
MyModel.findOne({_id: id}, (error, result) => {
   if (!error) {
      const newObject = {...result, toto: "toto"};
   }
});
```

The problem is that applying a spread operator to **result** transform it in a wierd way:

```
newObject: {
   $__: {
      $options: true,
      activePaths: {...},
      emitter: {...},
      getters: {...},
      ...
      _id: "edh5684dezd..."
   }
   $init: true,
   isNew: false,
   toto: "toto",
   _doc: {
      _id: "edh5684dezd...",
      oneFieldOfMyModel: "tata",
      anotherFieldOfMyModel: 42,
      ...
   }
}
```

I kind of understand that the object result is enriched by mongoose to permit specific interactions with it but when I console.log before doing so it depict a simple object without all those things.

I would like not to cheat by doing **...result._doc** because I abstract this part and it won't fit that way. Maybe there is a way to copy an object without eriched stuff.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look at its `toString` method. Thats what you see inside of console.log

Comment: Doing a `toString` on the result returns the simple object with only my fields so it's seems like the object is normal but it's when I try to use spread operator that it changes the object structure. It does exactly the same with `Object.assign()`.

Comment: Yeah well then do `console.log( result.toString )` to have a look how it works...

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can use the Mongoose `Document.toObject()` method. It will return the underlying plain JavaScript object fetched from the database.

```
const newObject = {...result.toObject(), toto: "toto"};
```

You can read more about the `.toObject()` method [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject).

Comment: Ok, simple as that, that was exactly what I was looking for but failed to find :) Thanks, hope it will help more people.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a follow up, after doing this I'm not able to use newObject.toJSON() which I could have used earlier as result.toJSON(). Any alternative here?

Comment: You can also use `.lean` directly on your db query, read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and found some alternatives apart from the previous answer.

Option 1 [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

`The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the modified target object.`

example:

```
Object.assign(result, {toto: "toto");
```

Options 2 [Document.prototype.set()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-set):

`Sets the value of a path, or many paths.`

```
doc.set("toto", "toto")
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone it can be helpful:

```
const newObject = {
    ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)),
    toto: "toto"
};
```

> But there are restrictions if you use Dates, functions, undefined,
> regExp or Infinity within schema