# Mongoose: Losing previously set values from newly created and updated schema document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an async function where I first update a document below:

```
  const saveToCurrentOrder= await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
      customerID,
      {
        orderStatus: "processed",
        categoryID,
        categoryName,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

And the new object returned as a result of update is:

```
{
  "customerID": "12345",
  "orderStatus": "processed",
   "categoryID": 234,
   "categoryName":"Food"
}
```

Now I basically want to replicate above document and say want to update orderStatus and customerID for the new document but keep remaining set data such as categoryName and categoryID unchanged. I am attempting to do that with spread operator while creating new schema object as shown below:

```
const saveToNextOrder = new Order({
      ...saveToCurrentOrder,
      orderStatus: "pending",
      customerID: "1236"
    });

await saveToNextOrder.save()
```

This creates a new object however, the new object loses categoryID and categoryName and only shows values that were set:

```
{
customerID: "1236",
orderStatus: "pending"
}
```

I am really lost as to why spread operator isnt working the way I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014504/es6-spread-operator-mongoose-result-copy) really helped me. Basically I failed to realize that `saveToCurrentOrder` is mongoose type object and not the same as a regular JS object. I needed to use [toObject](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) to convert it and then spread it. However, I had to specify _id to null so that it auto-generates and doesn't conflict with an existing _id from previous object.

```
const saveToNextOrder = new Order({
      ...saveToCurrentOrder.toObject(),
      _id: null,
      orderStatus: "pending",
      customerID: "1236"
    });

await saveToNextOrder.save()
```