# spread operator on moongose object is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nest

I am saving document to mongodb like this

```
async addUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
    const newUser = new this.userModel(user);
    return newUser.save();
}
```

now if i use this function

```
const newUser = await this.userService.addUser(user);
```

and print `newUser` it prints the values of valid object like `name,email`

now if i try

```
const clientInfo = { ...newUser, ...newClient.clientInfo };
```

it empty my `clientInfo` object

and if i try

```
const clientInfo = { ...newClient.clientInfo ,...newUser};
```

then this just shows the clientInfo properties.

I tried

```
async addUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
    const newUser = new this.userModel(user);
    return newUser.save().then((response) => response.toObject());
}
```

but `toObject` is not helping.

I just want to merge newUser object with someother object.

```
const clientInfo = { ...newClient.clientInfo ,...newUser};
```

What can be the issue?

**Update1**

[Tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014504/es6-spread-operator-mongoose-result-copy) that says using `toObject()` can help. But this did not work.

When i tried

```
newUser.save().lean()
```

but this shows

```
Property `lean` does not exist on type Promise<Document<any, any, User
```

Comment: What is it you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want to merge two objects

Comment: I don't use Mongoose, but it looks like the Mongoose object doesn't have those properties as **own** properties (just inherited ones). Spread syntax *(it's not an operator)* only uses *own* properties, not inherited ones. But again, I don't use Mongoose so I could be incorrect there. You can check by looking at `newUser` with the debugger, or by looking at the result of `Object.hasOwn(newUser, "name")` (or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(newUser, "name")` if your environment doesn't have `Object.hasOwn` yet.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [es6 spread operator - mongoose result copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014504/es6-spread-operator-mongoose-result-copy)

Comment: Im not sure but have a look at the `lean()` function. In `addUser()` -> `return newUser.save().lean()`. I think save() will return a mongoose object whereas lean returns a plain js object.